# How to escape from mouseListener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener

I have:

- class extended from JFrame;
- an list of JTextField's elements - JTextField[] pix.

When clicking on pix[i] - JFrame must iconified and next click at any point of screen must changes exactly that textField (pix[i]) without any influence on another textFields, then frame must normalized and any mouseClicks after that (not on textField) couldn't influenced on that elements.

Clicks outside of JFrame processed with jnativehook library.

That part of code here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pix.length; i++){
     int tmp = i;
     pix[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
             GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseAdapter(){
                 public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e){
                     pixelChoose(pix[tmp]);
                     setState(Frame.NORMAL); 
                 }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

P.S.: I've tried to use

```
GlobalScreen.removeNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseAdapter() {
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    }
});
```

but don't actually know how to use this correctly.

P.S.[2]: if you have another solution of that question, you are welcome to type it into the answers - it will be great :>

**EDIT!**
I was buisy and now I'm here with solution:

```
NativeMouseAdapter adapter = new NativeMouseAdapter(){
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e){
          pixelChoose(pix[tmp]);
          setState(Frame.NORMAL);
          GlobalScreen.removeNativeMouseListener(this);
    }
};
MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
          GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(adapter);
    }
};
pix[i].addMouseListener(listener);
```

Comment: You need a reference to the anonymous NativeMouseAdapter you added in the first place.

Comment: @matt, how? Can you show some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NativeMouseAdapter adapter = new NativeMouseAdapter(){
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e){
          pixelChoose(pix[tmp]);
          setState(Frame.NORMAL);
          GlobalScreen.removeNativeMouseListener(this);
    }
};
MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
          GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(adapter);
    }
};
pix[i].addMouseListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add (after the setState) code to remove the MouseListener.

```
 setState(Frame.NORMAL); 
 for (int i = 0; i < pix.length; i++){
     pix[i].removeMouseListener(MouseAdapter::this); 
 }
```

`pix` must be effectively final, and I hope MouseAdapter::this works for the anonymous MouseListener.

---

*MouseAdapter::this fails*

Instead of

```
 pix[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

hold the MouseListener in its own variable:

```
 MouseListener cat = new MouseAdapter() { ... };
 pix[i].addMouseListener(cat);
```

And later do in the inner callback do

```
      pix[i].removeMouseListener(cat);
```

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Comment: thanks, finger up from me) It will be useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you create the mouse listener, you need to keep a reference.

```
NativeMouseAdapter adapter = new NativeMouseAdapter(){
             public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e){
                 pixelChoose(pix[tmp]);
                 setState(Frame.NORMAL); 
      }
}
GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(adapter);
```

Then when you want to remove it, you use that reference.

```
GlobalScreen.removeNativeMouseListener(adapter);
```

Comment: you are mate:) thx for fastest answer in comments and very useful part of code! big finger up to you:)

Comment: but how to create an mouse listener with reference to array's elements? pixelChoose(pix[tmp]); - tmp is not identified... I must to create listener in loop?

Comment: What is the error it is giving you, it should be the same as your previous method. You might have to explicitly declare tmp as final. ie. `final int tmp = i`

Comment: what way to remove listener after his work? if it couldn't placed here, please, post as answer. Do not understand... add and then remove - zero result, cause program don't waits while click obtain...(

Comment: You want to remove the listener in the 'nativeMouseClicked` method?

Comment: mouseClick(){
...
nativeMouseClick(){...}
removeNativeMouseClick...(){...}
}
removeMouseClick();
something like this, but any method must processed...